How to scale a view matrix to display a nautical chart in correct compilation scale?
Background
I'm developing a nautical chart viewer app.
The source data (Electronic Nautical Chart) used is a vector-based chart. The geometry is given in latitude and longitude coordinates. The app transforms these coordinates in steps to finally display them on my monitor. The current implementation applies the following transformations:

Lat/lng are transformed using Mercator projection to normalized x/y values (0-1).
The normalized mercator coords are transformed into "view space" coords, a value between -1 and 1. Coordinates that map to values outside that range are not displayed.
Transform view space coords to screen space, i.e. map the coords to the monitor.

The view matrix in step 2 is where scaling is applied (zooming level).
The problem
I'm struggling to understand how I can calculate the appropriate scaling factor in order to display the chart in the scale (compilation scale) that the chart producer intended it to be displayed in. It's the display_scale argument I'm interested in calculating (when calling the following function). The current implementation of the view matrix (step 2) looks like this.
sf::Transform get_view_matrix(float display_scale, float aspect_ratio) {
  sf::Transform translation;
  sf::Transform scaling;

  // Calculate viewport width in Mercator coordinates based on display scale
  float w = 2.0f * display_scale;

  // Calculate height based on the aspect ratio and display scale
  float h = w / aspect_ratio;

  // Translation: move origin to center of the calculated rectangle
  translation.translate(-1. / 2.0f, -1. / 2.0f);

  // Scaling: map width and height to the -1 to 1 range
  scaling.scale(sf::Vector2f(1.0f / (w / 2.0f), -1.0f / (h / 2.0f)));

  // Return the matrix, which will apply translation, then scaling
  // on the transformed coordinate
  return scaling.combine(translation);
}

The compilation scale of the chart is 1:180000.
The geometry appears nicely, I'm able to zoom in and out by changing the display_scale arbitrarly.
